# Pythonanywhere Django Error running WSGI application ImportError:

Tags: python, django, wsgi, pythonanywhere, django-wsgi

I am trying to build a webapp in Pythonanywhere, and am trying to install [django-filter module](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/index.html).

I have installed the module through PIP and made all the required changes in settings.py, and app's views, models and the HTML page. Though the module is working in my local machine, in Pythonanywhere I am getting the following error

```
2017-06-09 05:07:18,654: Error running WSGI application
2017-06-09 05:07:18,656: ImportError: No module named 'django_filters'
2017-06-09 05:07:18,656:   File "/var/www/user_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 29, in <module>
2017-06-09 05:07:18,656:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2017-06-09 05:07:18,657: 
2017-06-09 05:07:18,657:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
2017-06-09 05:07:18,657:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2017-06-09 05:07:18,657: 
2017-06-09 05:07:18,657:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
2017-06-09 05:07:18,657:     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2017-06-09 05:07:18,657: 
2017-06-09 05:07:18,658:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
2017-06-09 05:07:18,658:     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2017-06-09 05:07:18,658: 
2017-06-09 05:07:18,658:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
2017-06-09 05:07:18,658:     module = import_module(entry)
```

My wsgi file is as follows. I don't know how to edit it.

```
# This file contains the WSGI configuration required to serve up your
# web application at http://user.pythonanywhere.com/
# It works by setting the variable 'application' to a WSGI handler of some
# description.
#
# The below has been auto-generated for your Django project

import os
import sys

# add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = u'/home/user/django_project'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, project_home)



# set environment variable to tell django where your settings.py is
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_project.settings'


# serve django via WSGI in Django < 1.7
# import django.core.handlers.wsgi
# application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
# serve django via WSGI in Django >= 1.7
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I really don't know how to address this error. Can someone please help? TIA

Comment: Do you have `django_filters` installed?

Comment: Even if you install django_filters using `pip3.5 install --user django-filter` it is not being installed. Must be some bug in pythonanywhere. It has nothing to do with wsgi or django.

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- anything you install using pip should work fine.  Are you sure you've installed if for the same Python version as the one your website is using?   If you're using a virtualenv, are you sure it's properly configured on the "Web" tab?